# Error during execution of console_scripts in setup.cfg

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

While running the console_script entry point defined in setup.cfg I am getting the below error. not sure why its complaining about the positional args.

```
start-prediction-engine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/start-prediction-engine", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(app())
TypeError: __call__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'scope', 'receive', and 'send'
```

here is the content in setup.cfg file

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
  start-prediction-engine = prediction_engine.prediction_engine:app
```

in the file prediction_engine.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("prediction_engine:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8888, reload=True, log_level="info")
```

Answer (score 1):

I fell into this same trap.

The issue is you're trying to register a console script to the `app` object (which I'm assuming is a FastAPI app instance).

Console scripts must be registered to a function. See the introduction [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point) for more information.

To remedy this, you can simply create a function that runs your app:

```
# prediction_engine.py
def main():
    uvicorn.run("prediction_engine:app", 
                host="0.0.0.0", 
                port=8888, 
                reload=True,
                log_level="info")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Adding the `if __name__ == "__main__":` section is unnecessary if you will always run from your console script, but this also lets you run it by doing i.e.

```
python prediction_engine.py
```

Finally, you'll want to point your console_script entry in your setup.cfg to the `main()` function:

```
# setup.cfg
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
  start-prediction-engine = prediction_engine.prediction_engine:main
```

Incidentally, the error you're getting

```
TypeError: __call__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'scope', 'receive', and 'send'
```

is what happens when you try to call the FastAPI `app` instance (i.e. `app()`) which is what the generated executable does.